# How to feed a backslash to Swift-mailer setPassword

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have a problem trying to insert a password containing a backslash in Swift-mailer setPassword, like so:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.myserver.com', portnumber)
  ->setUsername('username@email.com')
  ->setPassword('Somepassword\');
```

The problem is that PHP will interpret the backslash as an escape and will throw an error, but if I escape the backslash adding another one the password will not be correct.

I also tried using the ASCII code for a backslash and putting everything into a variable, giving setPassword something like this:

```
$password = 'Somepassword'.chr(92);
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.myserver.com', portnumber)
  ->setUsername('username@email.com')
  ->setPassword($password);
```

Is there a way to make a password containing a backslash work? I can't change the password.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to escape it with another backslash

```
->setPassword('Somepassword\\');
```

This will be interpreted as:

```
Somepassword\
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I did try that solution before without results, but then I tried again on another server and it turns out my issue was not with the backslash, after all. I'll keep debugging.